# Role-based, one controller for each (Auth/ACL)

Tags: cakephp, authentication, acl

I have this database:

`Roles` (id, name) -> `hasMany Users`

`Users` (id, role_id, username, password) -> `belongsTo Roles`

So, usually I have three roles: Administrator, Resale and Client. I use one controller for each because it is easier to manage the views.. then I used to use pure Session, you know, I just store in Session all User Data and then in each controller I just check if the role is corresponding to that Role.

Now I want to use Auth/ACL Component because I got tired of reinventing the wheel.. the problem is: **I have no ideia how to program the Role thing!** if you give me the stepping stones I will be happy.

Here is my code:

`AppController`

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
    'Acl',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
        )
    ),
    'Session'
);

public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'users',
      'action' => 'login'
    );
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array(
      'controller' => 'HERE SHOULD BE THE ROLE CONTROLLER??',
      'action' => 'add'
    );
}
```

`UsersController`

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
public $name = 'Users';

function index(){ }

function login(){
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your username or password was incorrect.'));
    }
}

function logout(){
    $this->Session->setFlash('Good-Bye');
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

`AdministratorsController` (similar to Resales or ClientsController)

```
class AdministratorsController extends AppController{

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

Comment: Try [Tiny Auth](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/) for example. Core ACL is total overkill in 99% of all cases.

Comment: Seems to be nice, I'll try it.